# Calling PHP function when clicking <button type="submit">

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I inserted an onclick to my button but don't know where I'm going wrong here but it seems like the function is fired each time the page is loaded.

How can I call the function **ONLY** when clicking on the button itself

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="<? $query = DB::update('ads')->set(array('sale_agreed' => '999'))->where('id_ad', '=', $msg_thread->ad->id_ad)->execute(); ?>"><?=_e('ACCEPT This Offer')?></button>
```

Any take on this? Thanks ;-)

Comment: You can not call php function like you have done. You should get basic knowledge about jquery/javascript

Comment: Use cannot call server side function from client side in this way, You should use AJAX and JS

Comment: just submit your form and in backend perform your db operation

Comment: I don't know why the question is closed !. replace your code with this `<button type="submit" name="buttonClicked" value="1" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="
<? 
if(!empty($_GET['buttonClicked'])){
    $query = DB::update('ads')->set(array('sale_agreed' => '999'))->where('id_ad', '=', $msg_thread->ad->id_ad)->execute();  
}
?>">
<?=_e('ACCEPT This Offer')?>
</button>  `

Comment: @Accountantم Looks like you better to read the duplicate article too ...

Comment: @Teemu Looks like you didn't get my code

Comment: @Accountantم What's the point? All that PHP is executed before the document is even delivered to a browser.

Comment: @Teemu You are just confused because his PHP code is inside strange place - the `onclick` .He wanted to execute the PHP  code **only** if the button is clicked,so  I added a condition before executing the PHP code to check if the button is clicked or not, if the button is clicked then execute his PHP code. I know his PHP code Is in client side code place, but this should not confuse a user with rep like you. you better be focused when reading the problem. EDIT: I also added a parameter in the button so the server can check

Comment: @Accountant > I have a feeling that you're on the right track with this rather simple solution although it doesn't seem to be working for me yet... I also tried with statement *if (isset($_POST* instead of *!empty($_GET* but still won't do it for me don't know why... Any further input?

Comment: @DavidG What is the method of the`< form>` of your button? if POST , then change the condition to `!empty($_POST['buttonClicked'])` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of jQuery Ajax to perform this operation.
Add a button with some id.

```
<button id="click-button"></button>
```

Inside your script tag.

```
$(document).read(function(){
    $("#click-button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
        url: "remote-file.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:"token=buttonclick",
        success: function(result){
            if(result != "fail"){
                //Perform actions with the results...
            }
        }});
    });
});
```

In you PHP `remote-file.php`

```
<?php
if(isSet($_POST['token']) && $_POST['token'] == 'buttonclick'){
    $result = myFunction();
    echo $result;
}else{
    echo "fail";
}

function myFunction(){
    // Perform your DB actions...
    return true; //Return your data
}
?>
```

Comment: that worked fine first time. Thanks for that much appreciated ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use php functions from client side. The attribute "onclick" fires a javascript funciont, not a php one.
In order to execute a php function with onclick, you have to make an Ajax request to the server.

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "some.php",
      data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
   })
    .success(function( msg ) {
         alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
      });
});
```

In the "url" variable you have to put the url to your php script, and the data object contains all the PHP $_REQUEST parameter to be send to the script. The success function executes once the script is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Button click is **client side** whereas PHP is **server side**, but you can achieve this by using `AJAX`.

```
$('.button').click(function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "some.php",
        data: { name: "John" }
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    });

});
```

**In your PHP file:**

```
<?php
    function abc($name){
        //your code here
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

You cant add php functions to client side button clicks.

You should get your PHP to check if the page has been submitted and then run your function

Comment: Why JS? Submitting a form makes a request ...

Comment: Very good point updated the answer.